# Как вывести теги?

Tags: mysql, laravel

есть запрос для ввода статей

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
            ->leftJoin('comments', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('comments.content_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                    ->where('comments.type', '=', 1);
            })
            ->leftJoin('likes', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('likes.content_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                    ->where('likes.type', '=', 1);
            })
            ->leftjoin('user_attributes', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('user_attributes.user_id', '=', 'articles.user_id');
            })
           // ->whereDay('articles.updated_at', '=' ,'DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())')
            ->select(
                'articles.id', 'articles.view', 'articles.title','articles.slug','articles.height','articles.updated_at',
                'user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.avatar',
                'articles.image', 'articles.published',DB::raw('count(comments.id) as comments'),
                DB::raw('sum(likes.like) as rait'))
            ->groupBy('articles.id')
            ->groupBy('user_attributes.fullname')
            ->groupBy('user_attributes.avatar')
            ->orderBy('height', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('rait', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('comments', 'DESC')
            ->take(30)
            ->get();
```

вывожу во view так:

```
@forelse($articles as $article)
            <div class="item">
                <a href="{{ route('post', $article->slug) }}" class="a-title">{{ $article->title }}</a>
                <div class="article_autor">
                    <div class="autor">
                        <img src="/storage/{{ $article->avatar }}" alt="{{ $article->fullname }}">
                        <span>{{ $article->fullname }} </span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="date">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->updated_at)->format('d M Y') }} <svg><use xlink:href="#time"></use></svg></p>
                </div>
                <img src="/storage/{{ $article->image }}" alt="{{ $article->title }}" title="{{ $article->title }}">
                <div class="article_meta">
                    <div class="box__comments">
                        <div class="item-meta meta-btn comments">
                            <svg><use xlink:href="#chat"></use></svg>
                            <span>{{ $article->comments }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item-meta eye meta-btn">
                            <svg><use xlink:href="#eye"></use></svg>
                            <span>{{$article->view}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="{{ route('post', $article->slug) }}" class="btn-blue">Читать дальше</a>
                </div>
                <div class="article__tags">

                </div>
            </div>
            @empty
        @endforelse
```

как вывести теги для каждой статьи, которые лежат в таблице

```
article_tags (таблица связи статьи и тегов)
id | article_id | tag_id
```

и сама таблица тегов

```
tags
id | title
```

Comment: Elequent? - нет, не слышал

Comment: нет,  не слышал, если можно на примере покажите

Comment: смотрите документацию https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent